# Remove unwanted characters at the end of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make this code better , its works now, but i think it can be better , i have a hook and one property is onChange that get value and can setState and return that value for value of input , in the middle of code , i should check two regex and if is not valid skip the setState and return that .

```
    onChange: (value) => {
      const validRegex = /^[\u0600-\u06EF\s]+$/;
      if (!validRegex.test(value)) {
        const regex1 = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/g;
        const regex2 = /[\u06F0-\u06F9]+$/;
        return value.replace(regex1, '').replace(regex2, '');
      }

      setData((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        name: value,
      }));
      return value;
    },
```

```
<input value={data.name} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
```

I replace , because i dont want miss text that user wrote. ,

example: value : This is name 1234 ===> result : This is name

Comment: I've given rewriting your title a shot to give you an idea of what we're looking for, feel free to improve it along those lines.

Comment: This code removes non-Unicode characters from a string, right? If so, perhaps that can be incorporated into the title

Comment: yeah @peterSO,  I want to deprive user just type arabic character , but because i want to to have previous character in the input , i should find that false character and replace with empty , otherwise in the middle string when user entered wrong character , the whole of string converted to empty suddenly

Comment: @tmohammad78 Does your input field look like `<input value={data.name} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />`? If not, could you please add it to the question?

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets, thank you for your attention

Comment: @tmohammad78 I opened the [arabic unicode symbols](https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/arabic/) and discovered that there are numbers `U+06F0 - U+06F9`, which you mentioned, and `U+0660 - U+0669`, which are inside our regex `\u0600-\u06EF`. Don't know if it's important, just putting it out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, **regular expression constants** are better be placed **outside** of component function. Otherwise they get recreated each change event.

Second, is there a purpose of changing value? If we enter the if statement, we will **not change the state**, so it will affect nothing. And we don't need to `return value;` in the end, too.

Third, in current configuration there is no need to have `regex2`, because if we get a string `\u0600\u06F0`, which is a **letter and a number** (if I understand correctly), we will remove the number later. If it's `\u06F0\u0600`, a reversed one, we won't remove it. Though anyway, in the end it doesn't matter, because operations inside the `if` statement won't change the state.

Fourth, we check for `/^[\u0600-\u06EF\s]+$/`. Because of the `+` in the end we can't have an **empty string**. I don't know if it's by design, but if we have only 1 letter, we can't delete it, we can only select it and type another letter to replace it, which may not be convenient.

In the end, the version of code that I see fitting the task is:

```js
  // arabic letters and signs without numbers
  const validRegex = /^[\u0600-\u06EF\s]+$/;

  const MyComponent = () => {

    // ...

    onChange: (value) => validRegex.test(value)
      && setData((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: value }));

  // ...

  }
```

*Please correct me if needed*

Comment: Great answer. I would have only added that a regex should have a comment with what was intended

Comment: @konijn, thank you! Good point, added a comment.